# Saving variables from entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have the text input of this entry box save to a list and then be printed. I cannot have it save the input upon the button press and it just prints the placeholder variable.

```
 names = []

 from tkinter import*

 class Trip:
     def __init__(self, parent):
        E_name = "q"
        self.En_name = "g"
        self.En_name = str(self.En_name)
        self.go = Frame(parent, width = 500, height = 450, bg = "snow", pady = 30, padx = 10)
        self.go.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.go.grid_propagate(0) # to reserve space required for frame
        self.tet = Frame(parent, width = 500, height = 450, bg = "snow")

        name = Label(self.go, text = "Name:", bg = "snow")
        name.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = E)
        self.E_name = Entry(self.go, width = 40, textvariable = self.En_name)
        self.E_name.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)


        menuButton = Button(self.go, text = "Continue", command = self.breakeverything)
        menuButton.grid(row = 8, column = 1, pady = 4)

     def breakeverything(self):
        names.append(self.En_name)
        print (names[0])
        self.E_name.delete(0, "end")

 #main routine
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Traveller Details")
    play = Trip(root)
    root.geometry("500x450+0+0")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

A `textvariable` is supposed to be a `tkinter.StringVar()`, not a primitive string. Your application looks simple enough that it shouldn't even need it. Take out `self.En_name`, take out the `textvariable`, and just retrieve the current value of the `Entry` widget in `breakeverything()` (which should no longer be an appropriate name):

```
def breakeverything(self):
    names.append(self.E_name.get())
    print(names[-1]) # printing the last name in the list seems more useful
    self.E_name.delete(0, "end")
```

I would also recommend moving `names` into `Trip.__init__` and making it an instance variable like everything else, with `self.names = []`. It'll make it easier to keep track of scopes.

Comment: Sorry I found a better way!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `textvariable` incorrectly (you must use one of the special Tkinter variables such as `StringVar`), but you don't need to use it at all. Simply save a reference to the widget, then call the `get` method when you want the value:

```
self.E_name = Entry(self.go, width = 40)
...
print("you entered: " + self.E_name.get())
```

If you insist o using `textvariable`, use a `StringVar` and then call the `get` method on that instead:

```
self.En_name = StringVar()
self.E_name = Entry(..., textvariable=self.En_name)
...
print("you entered: " + self.En_name.get())
```

Comment: Too complicated, why not ask a real person!

Comment: @AlanJones: what's complicated about it? You only have to change two lines of code. You _must_ call the `get` method on either the widget or the associated variable. That's how it is designed to work. There are no other ways to get data out of the widget.